# Child buttons do not take up entire gridlayout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a gridlayout, in which the width matches the screen size and the height is about 3/4 of the screen size. Within that gridlayout I have 4 buttons, equal size each taking 1/4 of the grid layout.  I have defined the grid layout to have 2 columns and 2 rows, and each button to take one column, row pair, yet the output has the 4 buttons, appear in the top right, all together taking less than 1/3 of the screen.

How do I get my buttons to take up the entire gridlayout?

[image]

Markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.WelcomeScreen">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="438dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


        <Button
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_row="1"
           android:layout_gravity="" />

    </GridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code and a screenshot of  what's actually happening..

Comment: Whenever you are asking about a layout problem, don't forget to post your xml files here. otherwise we can't solve your problem.

Comment: At maximum, each child can be as big as its parent. This is another negative effect of using nested layouts.

Comment: @bob Malooga, I am aware, but I did set the children to fill parent and they end up being the entire size of the parent, not the entire row coloumn size.

Comment: added picture thanks guys

Comment: Then the parent must fill its parent.

Comment: Note that `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` doesn't fill the parent. And that `fill_parent` has been deprecated about **5 years** ago.

Comment: Bob Malooga - I understand that wrap content does not fill parent, but as I stated earlier, fill parent OR match_parent, makes the child button take up the entire width or length of the screen

Comment: Thanks guys I solved it.  I made the size of each child button (0dp, 0dp).  And then I made the weight for each button (1,1).  The now each take up 1/4 of the parent.  Cheers.